# Laravel inversion of control , Type hinting constructor causes creation of instance automatically

Tags: php, laravel

```
class FooBar {

    public function __construct(Baz $baz)
    {
        $this->baz = $baz;
    }

}

$fooBar = App::make('FooBar');
```

In the above example the instance of Baz class is created automatically . Can anyone tell with example how this can be achieved outside laravel (How it is done) .From my reading I understand it is done using reflection .can anyone show it practically .

Comment: If you want to see an example, try reading through the Laravel code. Or try one of the many stand-alone dependency injection libraries available. For example: [Auryn](https://packagist.org/packages/rdlowrey/auryn), [Container](https://packagist.org/packages/league/container) or [Pimple](https://packagist.org/packages/pimple/pimple). They're all stand-alone libraries, so should be fairly easy to read the code and learn from it if you want to find out how these things are acheived.

Answer (score 1):

This particular case is relatively straightforward. You seem to be looking at the Laravel 4.2 IoC container documentation, so take a look in [the Laravel 4.2 source](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.2/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php#L494).

When [`App::make`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.2/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php#L409) is called, Laravel then calls [`build`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.2/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php#L494) on it. That uses PHP's [ReflectionClass](http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php) to inspect the given class's constructor. If the constructor takes no parameters, it just creates a new instance of the class and returns it. If the constructor takes parameters, the container recursively creates a new instance of each of them (using the same process) until they're all created, then creates a new instance of the class using those new instances and returns it.

Comment: I was asking about the type hinting at the constructor .

Comment: You might want to mention that in your question. What in particular do you want to know? The type hint in your example is the `Baz`. Laravel uses `ReflectionClass` to look through the parameters to the `FooBar` constructor, sees that it requires a `Baz` and instantiates one, then passes it in to the `FooBar` constructor. This is mostly done in `getDependencies`; that's what iterates through the parameters.